# Is async keyword an ultimate replacement for asyncio module?

Tags: python, async

Recently, there was a rise of interest toward asynchronous programming in Python community.  First prominent expression of this interest was the appearance of Asyncio —codenamed Tulip— framework [PEP 3156] in the standard library, and then, after a couple of years, the capability to write async code was introduced to the core of the language through `async def` construction [PEP 0492].

Some core developers who participated in designing Asyncio claim that the latter will actually benefit from `async` keyword introduction [[Andrew Svetlov on Google Plus]](https://plus.google.com/113184446080370879195/posts/VVnpZTLepgk).  From my perspective, though, it seems like `async` brings pretty much the same functionality as Asyncio does.  Perhaps it's just me missing something.

So, the question is, shall `async` take over Asyncio, or they are really that much different?
Was Asyncio just a playground before `async` has been approved?
Otherwise, how can Asyncio leverage the new `async` powers of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyncio` is a *set of libraries*. The PEP and implementation define event loop abstractions, protocols for tasks to interact with the event loop, and various I/O classes and concurrency primitives that can be used in asynchronous code. The way to write these tasks is/was to write a generator and the way to wait on the completion of another task is/was to `yield from that_task`.

`aync` *extends the language* with a different way to write generators (here called coroutines to avoid confusion) that is similar but more powerful and useful for writing asynchronous tasks with `asyncio` (and other, similar event loops). `await` is like `yield from` conceptually and in practice. The `async` PEP does not define any APIs (except the bare bones to support the new built-in type), and does not affect the `asyncio` API *at all*. It's simply a better way to use `asyncio`.